# Emojis/emoticons in Rich text field LWC?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I am trying to build a LWC component with a rich text editor and want to know how to get the emoji option in the tool bar.

Comment: Hey, @kruthi I have the same requirement, any luck?

Comment: Hi @VarunMK, I was just able to figure out the windows/mac emoji shortcut which you can use on any salesforce text fields. 
Go to any Text field and press (windows key + period Key) if you are using windows or (CTRL + CMD + Space) if mac. you get the emoji keyboard which is also supported by salesforce.
I am still looking for a button which shows the list of emoji. will update here if i find anything.

Comment: Thank you so much for the workaround. Works for me. In the SLDS page i did see that the rich text editor has a emoji symbol but not sure how we can get the images once we click it as u mentioned.